# ggplot2: plot is empty when using scale_y_continuous

Tags: r, ggplot2, scale

Using this data.frame

**Data**

```
banks <- read.table(text = c("
Date    Central_Bank    Al-Ahli CIB Arab_African_Bank   Misr    AbuDhabi    Qahira  Credit_Agricole Albarakah   Alt3meer_El_Eskan
20/11/2016  17.14   17.27   17.25   17.3    17.28   17  17.28   17.25   17.35   17
                            21/11/2016  17.39   17.25   17.15   17.3    17.25   17.2    17.25   17.25   17.31   17.1
                            22/11/2016  17.29   17.4    17.25   17.37   17.41   17.25   17.25   17.3    17.43   17.3
                            23/11/2016  17.3    17.4    17.3    17.32   17.41   17.3    17.3    17.25   17.35   17.25
                            24/11/2016  17.37   17.4    17.3    17.4    17.41   17.4    17.3    17.25   17.4    17.25"
                            ), header = T)
```

and this script

```
banks$Date <-  as.Date(banks$Date, format="%d/%m/%Y")

banks1 <- banks %>% 
  tidyr::gather("Bank", "Value", 2:11)


ggplot(banks1, aes(x = Date, y = Value, fill =Bank))+
  geom_bar(stat= "identity", position = "dodge", fill = "Blue")+
  facet_wrap(~Bank)
```

I got this plot

[image]

These values are the exchange rate USD/EGP. The fluctuations in the exchange rate are between 17 and 17.45. I want to zoom in to highlight these fluctuation so I used

```
  scale_y_continuous( limits = c(17, 17.5), 
                      breaks=c(17, 17.1,17.2, 17.3, 17.4, 17.5))
```

However, the final plot was empty. Any suggestion what went wrong?
[image]

Comment: geom_bar for time series data ?

Comment: @NathanDay
It doesn't make sense to me but someone wanted it this way. This was the first plot that came to my mind when I saw the data
https://www.dropbox.com/s/lv9gld6l64wucxc/banks3.png?dl=0

Comment: I think that's the better way to display, but if you have to do bars, you can fashion custom one's with `geom_ribbon`

Comment: @NathanDay Thanks. I will try it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Line graph also show the desired zoomed variation

```
ggplot(banks1, aes(x = Date, y = Value, fill = Bank))+
geom_line(stat= "identity", color = "Blue", size = 2)+
scale_y_continuous( limits = c(17, 17.5),
                      breaks=c(17, 17.1,17.2, 17.3, 17.4, 17.5)
                      )+
facet_wrap(~Bank)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can't plot a geom_bar without including the the whole bar. Try using geom_point to see that your code is fine, or change your lower bound from 17 to 0.

Comment: Written on phone - will add more details when I can.

Comment: Thanks for your time and help